# Tough integrals that can be easily beaten by using simple techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, soft-question, big-list

This question is just idle curiosity. Today I find that an integral problem can be easily evaluated by using simple techniques like [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820925/346183) to evaluate

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos{x}}{2-\sin{2x}}dx
\end{equation}

I'm even shocked (and impressed, too) by user [@Tunk-Fey's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803113/346183) and user [@David H's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/877817/346183) where they use simple techniques to beat hands down the following tough integrals

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2^x-1}\ \ln\left(2^x-1\right)}\ dx
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}\,\sqrt{x+1}\,\sqrt{2x+1}}\ dx
\end{equation}
So, I'm wondering about *super* tough definite integrals that can easily beaten by using simple techniques with only a few lines of answer. Can one provide it including its evaluation?

To avoid too many possible answers and to narrow the answer set, I'm interested in knowing tough integrals that can easily beaten by **only** using clever substitutions, simple algebraic manipulations, trigonometric identities, or the following property

\begin{equation}
\int_b^af(x)\ dx=\int_b^af(a+b-x)\ dx
\end{equation}

I'd request to avoid using contour/ residue integrals, special functions (except gamma, beta, and Riemann zeta function), or *complicated* theorems. I'd also request to avoid *standard* integrals like

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\cos x}{1+e^{1/x}}\ dx&=\sin 1\tag1\\[10pt]
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log ax}{b^2+c^2x^2}\ dx&=\frac{\pi\log\left(\!\frac{ab}{c}\!\right)}{2bc}\tag2\\[10pt]
\int_0^1\frac{1}{(ax+b(1-x))^2}\ dx&=\frac{1}{bc}\tag3\\[10pt]
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^kx}{\sin^kx+\cos^kx}\ dx&=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag4\\[10pt]
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}\ dx&=\log\left(\!\frac{b}{a}\!\right)\tag5
\end{align}

Comment: If they can be easily beaten by simple techniques, they aren't so tough!

Comment: @RobertIsrael But perhaps the OP is looking for ones that look tough, say with a lot of terms or that would be very hard to solve except for the fact that there is some non-obvious way to shorten the process. It is definitely a (soft-question).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Seemingly, Achilles is not tough after all ☺

Comment: Hmm... This question is too subjective. Perhaps try to defime tough?

Comment: One of my favourite answers was about computing [$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\sin x\mathrm dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/655156/116182).

Comment: I think [the answer by Ishan Singh](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2081059/356647) deserves more attention in light of the complexity of other methods there.

Answer (score 16):

My favourite example of this is [@SangchulLee's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379720) to [@VladimirReshetnikov's question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326557/integral-large-int-0-infty-fracdx-sqrt47-cosh-x) which asks to verify 
the correctness of the identity 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]{7 + \cosh x}}= \frac{\sqrt[4]{6}}{3\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2 .$$

The other answers indicate the "toughness" of this integral, resorting to all sorts of special functions  such as elliptic functions,
hypergeometric functions, or *Mathematica*.

However, the integral can be brilliantly shown to be a few substitutions away from the form of a beta function integral.

Lee makes a chain of simple substitutions [which  he desecribes here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379605), to obtain 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(a+ \cosh x)^s} = \frac1{(a+1)^s} \int_0^1 \frac{v^{s-1}}{\sqrt{(1-v)(1-\frac{a-1}{a+1} v)}} dv.$$

The closed formed of this integral for general $a$  is certainly non-elementary, but our special case $a=7$ and $s=4$ is different
for a very neat reason:

When $a=7,$ $\frac{a-1}{a+1}$ is equal to $\frac34$, but since we have the triple angle formula
$\displaystyle \, \cosh(3 x)=4\cosh^3 x-3 \cosh x,$ the integral can be rewritten (with $v=\operatorname{sech}^2 t$) as
 $$2^{5/4} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cosh t}{\sqrt{\cosh 3t}} dt$$
which can be easily brought to the form of a beta function.

(Note that we can find a similar closed form (with $a=7$) for $s=3/4$.)

Answer (score 11):

Ramanujan's master theorem can be applied to a wide range of (sometimes extremely complicated) definite integrals, allowing them to be evaluated in less than a line of computations. The theorem states:

If $f(x)$ has a series expansion of the form:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{\lambda(k)}{k!} x^k$$

then

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x) dx = \Gamma(s)\lambda(-s)$$

Here one has to use an appropriate analytic continuation of $\lambda(k)$. This is a generalization of an old theorem obtained by Glaisher stating that:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k a_k x^{2k}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}a_{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

where again an appropriate analytic continuation of the expansion coefficients is assumed.

Example: From the series expansion of the Bessel function of the first kind $J_{\alpha}(x)$ it is very easy to compute that:

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^p J_{\alpha}(x)dx = 2^p\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha + 1 +p}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha + 1 -p}{2}\right)}$$

for $-(\alpha + 1)<p<\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 9):

Feynman's trick, Frullani's theorem, symmetry tricks, [Glasser's master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html), the Laplace transform, Fourier (Legendre/Chebyshev) series expansions and the Euler beta function gave me at least the $80\%$ of my reputation points, but the day still has to come, to be prouder than [this massacre](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266181/a-nasty-integral-of-a-rational-function/592490#592490) through the residue theorem.

---

I have just realized I forgot to mention Wilf's wonder: [creative telescoping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94722/stirlings-formula-proof/1409131#1409131).

Comment: second link is also to glasser's master theorem

Comment: @AndresMejia: I am really bad with copy&paste. Thanks, now fixed.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Really I understand  your beautiful solutions and learn those. Indeed you teach me. +1

Answer (score 8):

There is **a lot** of 'tough looking' integrals which can be solved by various tricks, but usually it requires more than a few lines of proof.

This is a really soft question, because 'tough looking' integral is a very subjective term (note that I use it instead of just 'tough' because I agree with Robert's comment).

I suggest the book [Inside Interesting Integrals](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493912766), it is full of tricks for solving definite integrals.

---

My own example of solving an integral using only substitution and algebraic manipulations.

Solve (not really tough, but not simple either):

> $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)(\pi^2+\ln^2 x)}$$

Let's introduce a parameter:

$$I(v)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(v+x)(\pi^2+\ln^2 x)}$$

Let's make a change of variable:

$$x=e^t$$

$$I(v)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^t dt}{(v+e^t)(\pi^2+t^2)}$$

$$I(v)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(v+e^t) dt}{(v+e^t)(\pi^2+t^2)}-v \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ dt}{(v+e^t)(\pi^2+t^2)}=1-v J(v)$$

Now let's make another change of variable:

$$t=-z$$

$$I(v)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-z} d(-z)}{(v+e^{-z})(\pi^2+z^2)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ dz}{(1+v e^z)(\pi^2+z^2)}=\frac{1}{v} J \left( \frac{1}{v} \right)$$

Now we get:

> $$1-v J(v)=\frac{1}{v} J \left( \frac{1}{v} \right)=I(v)$$
>
> $$v J(v)+\frac{1}{v} J \left( \frac{1}{v} \right)=1$$

We immediately get the correct value for the original integral:

$$J(1)=I(1)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x)(\pi^2+\ln^2 x)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

---

As another example, see this [2 line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1690962/269624) by Sangchul Lee of this:

$$\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx=0$$

This is problem C2.1 from the book I mentioned, but the book offers a very long and complicated solution. Which shows that simplicity of integrals is relative.

Comment: What makes you think of introducing the parameter $v$ this way?

Comment: @Hans, this is the usual way when people want to use Feynman's trick (differentiation under the integral sign), or a functional equation like in this case. But to tell the truth, when I've encountered this integral it was already with a parameter. The substitution and functional equation was my own idea though

Comment: I see. I was just wondering what made you or someone who want to use Feynman's trick put $v$ where you put it instead of somewhere else. I suppose it is experience.

Comment: @Hans, it is experience, and before experience it's luck and a lot of failed attempts. This is the only way to gain experience

Comment: Even without setting the parameter, we can derive I(1) in the same way, since the substitutions will still regenerate the integral. The parameter is useful for the derivatives of I(v) at v=1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Some integrals I would consider:

1. $\int(\frac{x^4}{1+ x^6})^2 dx$ . This integral involves a very interesting trigonometric substitution.
2. $\int[\ln(x)\arcsin(x)] dx$. It is one of the few integrals which contain a logarithmic and an inverse trig function. It is an interesting one.
3. $\int \sin(x)\arctan(\sqrt{\sec(x)-1}) dx$. Once again, another interesting trigonometric substitution.